# HMAC webhook validation, from envelope callback

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

I read through the instructions [here](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/connect/validate/), which works if you're using Connect at the "account level" (i.e. all envelopes get sent through one account).

Our use case involves requiring a customer to log into DocuSign using their own account, so I'm now setting a callback on the envelope. When I receive the callback in this scenario, the HMAC signature headers aren't sent (X-DocuSign-Signature-1, X-DocuSign-Signature-2, etc.).

Has anyone experienced this? I'm in ruby/rails, using the docusign_esign gem, version 2.0.0.

I see an include_hmac parameter in DocuSign_eSign::ConnectCustomConfiguration, but it's not clear to me if you can use a custom configuration with an envelope-level callback.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The `eventNotification` object now includes an attribute `includeHMAC`.

If HMAC is set up at the account level, and `includeHMAC` is set to `"true"` then the HMAC headers will be included for per-envelope webhooks.

Unfortunately, the API call for setting up HMAC at the account level is not currently available. So customers need to have account-wide Connect to set the HMAC secret.

HMAC secrets are added and managed via the **Connect Keys** button in the **Connect** section of the eSignature Admin app:[image: Connect Keys button]

Comment: Thanks I'll check this out.

Comment: This sounds like a "ISV partner" integration.  You can follow the above process, but each customer will need to have/add at least one HMAC key to their account and share it with you.  Your integration will need to manage these on a per-customer basis.

If you wish to add security without the risk and overhead of managing per-customer secrets, I recommend using Mutual TLS instead.